# confusing validation error in rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Below is my model and controller from which i have filtered unneccessary lines.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
validates :password, presence: true, on: :create
validates :password_confirmation, presence: true, if: "password.present?"
validates :password, confirmation: true, 
  length: { in: 6..20}, if: "password.present?"
end
```

and controller-

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if params[:password].present?
      final_params = get_params
    else
      final_params = get_params.delete_if { |k,v| 
        k == "password" or k == "password_confirmation"
      }
    end

    if @user.update(final_params)
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private
  def get_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :date_of_birth, 
    :password,:password_confirmation, :mobile, :country, :state, :city, :pincode)
  end
end
```

the problem is when updating a data, it shows a validation error i.e password confirmation can not be blank. even if I enter something to that field and submit. and to find error i tried replacing "password.present?" from password confirmation validation with "password.exists?" and it showed exception that exists is not a valid method for "123456 : string" . 123456 is the current password in DB. why is it checking password against db ? and please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if params[:password].present?
    final_params = get_params
else
    final_params = get_params.delete_if { |k,v| k == "password" or k == "password_confirmation"}
end
```

Your problem is the first line here... your params are `params[:user][:password]` not `params[:password]` (you can see that in your `get_params` method)

So always your code is going to run the section that removes the password/confirmation

Also:

```
validates :password_confirmation, presence: true, if: "password.present?"
```

using a string of ruby in the validation is not generally considered good practice. How about adding a method like so:

```
validates :password_confirmation, presence: true, if: :confirmation_needed?
def confirmation_needed?
  password.present?
end
```

Finally, you also need to not check the length of password_confirmation if it hasn't actually been entered:

```
validates :password, confirmation: true, length: { in: 6..20}, 
          allow_blank: true, if: :confirmation_needed?
```

Comment: @Taryan East Thanks for the effort but, I did all you suggested but same problem still exists.

Comment: Add to your code some puts statements so we can see the value of `params`, `get_params` and `final_params`

Comment: well, I tried rendering the get_params before that gave me this hash {"first_name"=>"Sajan", "last_name"=>"Sahu", "email"=>"sajan@gmail.com", "password"=>"", "password_confirmation"=>"", "mobile"=>"98599999", "country"=>"C", "state"=>"S", "city"=>"C", "pincode"=>"3800000"} and final_params, gave same hash except that two key password and password_confirmation.

Comment: oh,params gave this{"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"patch", "authenticity_token"=>"qEG6HLjgColtMkRHpMMX8uY8g8pE6+s+kxuAuWlyXrqpNGuKNyJMM8GGQ+Ef78cYCwjbo6UispWWtK5KtnpGcw==", "user"=>{"first_name"=>"Sajan", "last_name"=>"Sahu", "email"=>"sajan.sahoo@gmail.com", "password"=>"", "password_confirmation"=>"", "mobile"=>"985999999", "country"=>"C", "state"=>"S", "city"=>"C", "pincode"=>"3800000"}, "commit"=>"Update User", "controller"=>"users", "action"=>"update", "id"=>"2"}

Comment: i am accepting your answer since now its working after a little tinkering

Answer (score 1):

It's never a good idea to chunk down the incoming parameters in the controller.

Rather, putting proper validations in the model is a good idea ! 
 hence cleaned up your controller.

Check below code:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to @user and return  if @user.update_attributes(get_params)
    # render will not be executed if the user is redirected & returned
    render :edit
  end

  private
  def get_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :date_of_birth, 
    :password, :password_confirmation, :mobile, :country :state, :city, :pincode)
  end
end
```

modified model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :password, presence: true, on: :create
  # above validation will be effective only for during new record creation.

  # below 2 validations will be cheked only if password is present in the params list.
  validates :password, confirmation: true, 
    length: { in: 6..20 }, if: validate_password? 
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true, if: validate_password? 

    private
    def validate_password?
      password.present?
    end
end
```

if still this does not help, then try to debug the self object in the validate_password? method. use raise self.inspect in the validation method to verify the incoming parameters.
That way you can track where you are going wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Now my model is almost same like you suggested. Its working now, so I will definitely try your answer after some time. +1